# How to Download Zip file from Ftp in C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I have to download zip file from ftp using c# code. 
i have used the following code.

```
        Uri url = new Uri("ftp://ftpurl");
        if (url.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
        {

            FtpWebRequest objRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(url);
            //Set credentials if required else comment this Credential code
            NetworkCredential objCredential = new NetworkCredential(userid, Pwd);
            objRequest.Credentials = objCredential;
            objRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            FtpWebResponse objResponse = (FtpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();

            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            int len = 0;
            FileStream objFS = new FileStream(@"E:\ftpwrite", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
            while ((len = objReader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                objFS.Write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            objFS.Close();
            objResponse.Close();

        }
```

but this code is not giving me the correct response as i want to save file from ftp and this code is writing the data from file  in bytes to my file.
my file is a zip file not a text file.
please help me what should i have to do or i am mistunderstanding.

Comment: Why are you using `StreamReader` at all? You're not reading directly from it - only from its `BaseStream`. Why not just use the stream?

Comment: You need to be more specific, "not giving me correct response" is not clear enough. What is going wrong? are you not getting the complete file ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand question correctly, but did you try E:\ftpwrite.zip?

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that it's something to do with the fact that you're using `StreamReader`. It's possible that on construction it's reading from the stream to try to determine the encoding. As you're not really *using* it - just the `BaseStream` - it's pointless and leads to unclear code.

Just use:

```
Stream inputStream = objResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

Additionally, you should use `using` statements for *all* the streams, and the response.

Oh, and if you're using .NET 4 or higher, use `Stream.CopyTo` to save yourself some time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to using free 3rd party libraries, you can use http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/download.html

It makes accessing the FTP a lot simpler IMO. Sample code (taken and slightly modified from their [documentation](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/doc/manual/index.html)):

```
using (FTPConnection ftp = new FTPConnection())
{
    ftpConnection.ServerAddress = "myserver";
    ftpConnection.UserName = userName;
    ftpConnection.Password = password; 
    ftpConnection.Connect();
    ftpConnection.DownloadFile(localFilePath, remoteFileName);
}
```